# vpn connection in nodejs using cisco-vpn package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to connect cisco vpn in Node js using cisco-vpn npm package.When i run the code it is getting failed.I am getting the below error.

"17 is Error: Command failed: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Cisco/Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client/vpncli.exe" disconnect"

system configuration:
OS: macOS Big Sur

```js
const vpn = require('cisco-vpn')({
    server: 'ipaddress',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
    
})
vpn.connect()
   .then(() => console.log('connected!'))
   .catch(e => {
        console.log("Error",e)
    })
 
vpn.disconnect()
    .then(() => console.log('disconnected!')).catch(e => {
        console.log("17 is",e)
    })
```

Comment: did vpn.connect execute? What command did you execute? Since the error only occur in the 'disconnect' listener, did your other command work?

Comment: No, it is giving this error: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 4.7.04056)

Comment: If you haven't figured this out yet, it looks like you need to set the `exe` option to the path on your system (`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn` for MacOS). It defaults to the Windows path you describe, which won't work on Mac.